# Installing RTSP Server Python bindings on Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to install Python bindings of RTSP Server on my Linux camera. I have working Gstreamer, opencv. When I try installing the below, I get the following error.

```
apt get-update
apt install gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0
```

```
Error : Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
```

I am fairly newto linux. Any help in explaining how to install RTSP Server on Linux will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks already

Comment: maybe Ubuntu server has problem and you have to wait some time. OR maybe you should set mirror servers for `apt`

Comment: I have no problem to install it on `Linux Mint 20.3` based on `Ubuntu 20.04` using mirror servers (in Poland).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by installing rtsp server using Gstreamer. For some unknown reasons, `apt install gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0` did not work on my Linux system. When I tried a different approach using Gstreamer's default rtsp server, it worked. The main line that helped me is,

`apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-rtsp`

Following this git repository step by step, you can achieve the same. https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/OpenCV-rtsp-server

Since I am writing in dockerfile, I had to change the line beginnings and syntax. Please dont forget to install Gstreamer plugins before installing rtsp server.